# Python telegram bot doesn't recognize text message

Tags: python, python-3.6, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Here I have a code for making a simple echo bot for telegram.

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
import logging

from data.constants import API_TOKEN, LOGGING_FORMAT

logging.basicConfig(format=LOGGING_FORMAT, level=logging.DEBUG)

updater = Updater(token=API_TOKEN)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher


def start(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                             text='Hello, dude.')


def echo(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                             text=update.message.text)


start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
echo_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, echo)


dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
dispatcher.add_handler(echo_handler)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```

I used a `python-telegram-bot` library for that.

For some reason, this bot recognizes only commands, but not plain text. I mean, the `echo` function echoes me only text, started from `/`. The function `start` works as it should.
The more interesting thing, that the same problem I had with another telegram-bot library - `aiogram`.

After got crazy I wrote to `python-telegram-bot` support to ask advice in solving my problem.
After running my snippet, support admitted, that it works fine for them and advice me last-hope-move: to try it on a new bot. I got new API key from @BotFather, tried it out, but now I'm here. That means my code still doesn't work properly.

There're some references, that could help us to solve it:

https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.html
[https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-–-Your-first-Bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Your-first-Bot)

But I suppose, that the problem is in my working environment, despite I tried to run my code on different fresh device.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to follow the Python Telegram samples where the CommandHandler and MessageHandler objects are defined when setting the handlers

```
dp = updater.dispatcher

dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command_handler))
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, main_handler))
```

Comment: do you mean I should add handlers right after `dp` declaration?

Comment: I mean don’t create the handlers and set them (2 instructions) but set and create them like in my example. I am thinking if there is a type mismatch maybe

Comment: so what the point? what should have change? the variable is initializing at both variants the same way. 
anyway, it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Being Python a strongly typed language I thought the object type validation (happening at runtime) could somehow be affected.

Comment: the main point is that my code is working fine for others, so how can object type validation work fine for one people and don't for others?
Also, we have no exceptions. It means, that object type validation is passed well.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: for a bot to recognize not only commands, but text messages either we need to [disable privacy mode](https://github.com/wrxck/telegram-bot-lua/issues/4)